# How do I call javascript code on RangeValidator error in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I use a RangeValidator on a text field and the error text gets set properly when the value is changed and it's not within the range specified. However, I want to run some Javascript as well but I can't seem to get the javascript to trigger.

How can I make javascript run on error?

I tried using onerror but that didn't seem to work:

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="maxUsersRangeValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="maxNumUsersTextBox" ErrorMessage="Error: max users must be between 100 and 1,000 users per batch" ForeColor="Red" MaximumValue="1000" MinimumValue="100" onerror="javascript:closeloading()" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Comment: _I want to run some Javascript as well..._ can you put your `Javascript` code?

Comment: The javascript is irrelevant for what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm just trying to get the javascript to be triggered in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CustomValidator:

```
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" EnableClientScript="true" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Error: max users must be between 100 and 1,000 users per batch" ClientValidationFunction="validateRange" ControlToValidate="maxNumUsersTextBox"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Then, validate the range with Javascript:

```
function validateRange(sender, args){
var cant = document.getElementById("maxNumUsersTextBox");
if(cant>=100 && cant<=1000){
   args.IsValid = true;
}else{
closeLoading();
   args.IsValid = false;
}
}
```

Comment: It's incorrect to return true/false, instead just use the name of the function in ClientValidationFunction, and change the method signature to (sender, args). Then set args.IsValid to true or false.

Comment: @moarboilerplate I'm not sure what you mean and how do I know to set args.IsValid to true or false?

Comment: This method returns true or false, right? It shouldn't be, because returning true or false doesn't really do anything. Instead, ASP.NET will pass objects to your javascript function if you let it, and the args object that it will pass to you is what you use to define if the validation failed. So make your ClientValidationScript = "validateRange" and then change `validateRange()` to `validateRange(sender, args)`. Then instead returning true or false, set args.IsValid = true/false

Comment: function validateRange(sender, args) {
    var textBox = document.getElementById("MainContent_maxNumUsersTextBox");

    if (parseInt(textBox.value) >= 100 && parseInt(textBox.value) <= 1000)
    {
        loading();
        //return true;
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
    else
    {        
        closeLoading();
        args.IsValid = false;
        //return false;
    }
}

I get a javascript error saying that it doesn't know what args.IsValid is (uncaught type error).

Comment: did you change the ClientValidationFunction to "validateRange" or does it still say "validateRange()" in your validator tag? Take a look at this example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx